# Apache Mod Rewrite old URL pattern to new one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm newbie in Apache Mod Rewrite stuff, I need help to write a rule:

**Old pattern:**

```
/{category_id}/{from}/{category_slug}-{page}/{id}/detail-{slug}
```

**New pattern:**

```
/{category_id}-{from}-{category_slug}/{id}-{slug}
```

**The REGEX rules for params are:**

```
    id:             \d+
    category_id:    \d+
    slug:           "^[a-z0-9-]+"
    category_slug:  "^[a-z0-9-]+"
    from:           "^[a-z0-9-]+"
    page:           \d+
```

I need to write the .htaccess rule to automaticaly redirect old pattern URLs to new ones with a permanent redirect 301.

**Example
Old URL:**

```
/2/categorie/tables-bureaux-1/213/detail-secretaire-des-annees-60-domino
```

**Expected new URL:**

```
/2-categorie-tables-bureaux/213-detail-secretaire-des-annees-60-domino
```

For the moment, I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/detail-([a-z0-9-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule /%1-%2-%3/%5-%6$ [R=301,L]
```

I'm using the PHP Symfony2 framework which already have this .htaccess rule - so I'm not sure where to write the new one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simplified rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)-([^-]+)/([0-9]+)/detail-([^\s?]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2-%3/%5-%6? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure this rule is placed as **very first rule** in your main .htaccess file.

Comment: I've tested your solution but it doesn't work.BTW, I made an edit on my post because the new pattern rule changed...

Comment: Hmm you changed a lot. Is this some CMS/PHP ?

Comment: it's a symfony2 (framework php) project; i need to change urls for seo problems...

Comment: Ok you need to provide sample of `before` and `after` URLs for this redirect.